# windows 2008 r2 Change owner on multiple folders

Tags: directory, owner

I've a quest to change the owner on about 800 folders.  The owner should be equal to the  folder name. I've tried something like this:

```
set /p userDir=username
ICACLS "D:\test\%userDir%" /setowner "domain\%userDir%" /T
```

But I get the error message

> "ICACLS: Comparison between user names and security IDs was not made"

If I change `%userDir%` to an actual folder name it will work. Could you please tell what is wrong?

Comment: Does look too overly complex? I see one of the actual scripts for changing ownership of folder to user of same name of folder is posted by 
Pimiento benzieglmeier May 19, 2014 at 4:11 PM

[Change Permissions and Ownership Powershell](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/413259-change-permissions-and-ownership-powershell)